# How to get last element/element at the specified index in the ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, collections

**1.** How to get last element in the `ObservableCollection`?

**2.** How to get element at the specified index in the `ObservableCollection`?

In java it's just **1.**`collection.get(collection.size()-1);`  **2.**`collection.get(index);` How to get it in c#?

Comment: 1. collection[collection.count-1]  2. collection[index]

Comment: `collection.Last()` and `collection.ElementAt(collection.Count()-1)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. `collectionName.Last()` will return the last element in the collection. Make sure you have a reference to System.Linq
2. `collectionName[4]` will return the 5th element in the collection (collection is zero-based).

Answer (score 3):

**Collection:**

```
ObservableCollection<string> collection = new ObservableCollection<string> {"one", "two", "three", "four"};
```

**Without System.Linq;**

```
collection[2]; //returns three
collection[collection.Count - 1]; //returns four
```

**With System.Linq;**

```
collection.Last(); //returns four
collection.ElementAt(collection.Count - 1); //returns four
collection.ElementAt(1); //returns two
```